# C program with a function which checks if integer A contains integer B

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int funkcija(int num, int num2)

{

    int doesContain;



    if (doesContain == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;


}

int main(void)

{

    int num, num2;

    scanf("%d", num);
    scanf("%d", num2);

    printf("%d", funkcija(num, num2));


    return 0;

}
```

So basically, I need to make a function which takes number 1 and number 2, checks if number2 is in number1, then returns 0 or 1.

So for example, if number 1 is let's say '2452325678', and number 2 is '7', number 1 DOES contain number 2 and the statement is true. But if num1 is '2134' and num2 is '5', the statement is false.

It needs to be done PRIMITIVELY, without arrays and whatnot.

I need any help I can get with the algorithm.

Comment: Is B only one digit?

Comment: If number2 is always one digit, start % with 10 until you have only one num left, and compare remainder at each step.

Comment: B is always only one digit

Comment: That's an idea, but how would I go on to "test" the entire integer with % 10?

Consider I have 1234567. If I % that with 10, I'm going to get 7. How do I get to the 6?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm dumb!

For people with this problem who might stumble upon this thread:

num1 % 10 = gives you the last digit of the number

After that you simply num1 / 10 to remove the last digit and go on.

Common sense, something I don't have while I'm tired!

Comment: you need to use `&num` and `&num2` with scanf

Answer (score 0):

```
int numsub(int haystack, int needle)
{
    for (; haystack; haystack /= 10)
       if (haystack % 10 == needle)
           return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fairly simple, works by keeping dividing the number by 10 and each time
checking if currentNumber % 10 == the digit checked.
that's all.
example:

```
int i;
int num;
int flag;
int digit;
flag = 1;
num = 1234;
digit = 2;
while(num != 0 && flag)
{
    if(num % 10 == digit)
    {
     flag = 0;
    }
    else
    {
    num = num / 10; 
    }
}
if(flag == 1)
{
    //flag stays set,which means that digit is not inside num
}
else
{
 //flag is not set, which means that digit is indeed a part of num.
}
```